# How to Clear the ngModel value coming from other component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component in which [(ngModel)]=attrProps._value is getting set on user input and also getting value when already present by default. 
Now there is a button which leads to a toggle button for value option when the user wants to have custom value.

But when the user clicks on the refresh button the value in the input field should get clear?

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'n-customValue',
    template: `
            <mat-form-field class="inputfield-attr-view">
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="attrProps._value" placeholder="{{bKeeperService.getAttributeType(attrProps).displayAs}}">
                <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="revertIcon()" class="editButton">
                    <img class="attributeview-button" src="../../assets/icons/refresh.svg">
                </mat-icon>
              </mat-form-field>
    `
})
export class customValueComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() clickEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(public myservice: customService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }
    
    revertIcon() {
        this.clickEvent.emit('REVERT_EVENT');

    }
}
```

I tried using element ref but could not solve it.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'n-customvalue',
    template: `
            <mat-form-field class="inputfield-attr-view">
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="attrProps._value" #searchInput placeholder="{{bKeeperService.getAttributeType(attrProps).displayAs}}">
                <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="revertIcon()" class="editButton">
                    <img class="attributeview-button" src="../../assets/icons/refresh.svg">
                </mat-icon>
              </mat-form-field>
    `
})
export class customvalueComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() clickEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
    @Input('nAttrProps') nAttrProps;
    @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: ElementRef;

    attrPropsValue;
    constructor(public myservice: customService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

    revertIcon() {
        this.clickEvent.emit('REVERT_EVENT');
        this.searchInput.nativeElement.value = '';

    }
}
```

Comment: where is this `attrProps._value` coming from? from which component, you should share that code here.

Comment: `attrProps._value` is coming from customService where there is a function to return attrProps

Comment: share your full code here

Comment: Its is very long code however I am sharing you the service code. 
  `getAttributeType(attrProps) {
    if(attrProps && attrProps._key && this.electronService.AttributeTypes[attrProps._key]) {
    return this.electronService.AttributeTypes[attrProps._key];
    }
    return '';
  }`

Comment: where you assign the value  for `attrProps._value` in your component?

Comment: this template is being assigned to ` <ng-template [nAttrProps]="attrProps"></ng-template>`. I just want to have any method which can clear the input field after the refresh button click.

Comment: @Oliver, why not simply < mat-icon matSuffix (click)="attrProps._value=''">? (I don't see your "parent", but in parent you can have <n-customvalue (clickEvent)="attrProps.value=''">